# Create table using Matlab fprintf

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have  four vectors x,y,z,c

How do I get matlab to display it using fprintf in a table form with titles above each column like "title 1" and the x column below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example to get you going. I suggest reading the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?searchHighlight=fprintf) about fprintf also.

```
clear
clc

%// Dummy data
x = .1:.1:1;
y = 2:2:20;
z = x+y;

%// Concatenate data
A = [x; y ; z];

%// Open file to write
fileID = fopen('MyTable.txt','w');

%// Select format for text and numbers
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %6s %6s\n','x','y','z');
fprintf(fileID,'%.2f \t %.2f \t %.2f\n',A);
fclose(fileID);
```

Checking what MyTable looks like:

```
type ('MyTable.txt');



    x      y      z
0.10     2.00    2.10
0.20     4.00    4.20
0.30     6.00    6.30
0.40     8.00    8.40
0.50     10.00   10.50
0.60     12.00   12.60
0.70     14.00   14.70
0.80     16.00   16.80
0.90     18.00   18.90
1.00     20.00   21.00
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What if a \t is not enough? Eg: Too much digits.